# Passing NSString from one viewController to another without IBAction

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, parameter-passing

I am trying to pass an NSString variable from one view controller to the other but I have only been able to find tutorials and information on doing this by the use of a button IBAction but and have not been able to pass it successfully. Are there any easy alternatives without using a button?

```
#import "DetailController.h"
#import "City.h"
#import "VideoController.h"

@interface DetailController ()

@end

@implementation DetailController
@synthesize city, ClubName, Price, Vip, Promo, remain,p,deal,money,camera,cam;


- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self)
        {
            // Custom initialization
        }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    UIFont *labelFont=[UIFont fontWithName:@"Deutsch Gothic" size:20.0];
    UIFont *myFont=[UIFont fontWithName:@"Deutsch Gothic" size:30.0];
    UIFont *titleFont=[UIFont fontWithName:@"Deutsch Gothic" size:40.0];
    NSString * name= self.city.clubName;
    NSString * line= self.city.clubLine;
    NSString * description= self.city.promo;
    NSString * price= self.city.price;
    cam=self.city.camera;
    remain.font=labelFont;
    remain.text=@"VIP Remaining :";
    p.font=labelFont;
    p.text=@"Price :";
    money.font=myFont;

    deal.font=labelFont;
    deal.text=@"Promotions :";

    ClubName.font=titleFont;
    ClubName.text=name;
    Vip.font=myFont;
    Vip.text=line;
    Price.font=myFont;
    Price.text=price;
    Promo.font=labelFont;
    Promo.text=description;

}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@end
```

I am trying to pass cam or camera to videoController

Comment: Will you plz share your code how you trying to do this?

Comment: Post your code please, so we can understadd the ViewController hierachy

Comment: I apologize I have added the code where the string is located

Comment: Please share how you are trying to pass the value.

Comment: A Button has nothing special to pass data across, the `IBAction` is merely a means of assigning code to a button click event. Any code that would go inside this button would work outside the button. This question makes no sense

Comment: I apologize I am very new to xcode, the only reason i referenced a button is because all the tutorials i have found use a button and place the code within the IBAction method. I would like to know how I can get "cam" over to videoController.

Comment: @user3492592 Note on stackoverflow please use "@<username>" when replying to someone in a comment thread so that person is alerted to the comment. Again, google how to pass data between `viewController`'s. It is probably the most widely asked on stackoverflow next to `NSDateFormatter` questions. If the example uses an `IBAction` just use the code in the method. This has nothing to do with being new to Xcode, this is basic programming

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to `Push` between view controllers than you can create a property in view controller and before pushing view controller set the value.You can do this in following way:-

In View Controller2 declare a property

```
@property(nonatomic,strong) NSString *passedString;
```

in View Controller 1 do this

```
ViewController2 *vc2 = [ViewController2 alloc]initWithNibName:@"ViewController2" bundle:nil];
[vc setPassedString:@"Hello"];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:vc2 animated:YES];
```